# Finding the contour of a pair of multi-variable functions

Tags: plotting, graphics, mathematical-optimization

I have two functions `f[x,y,z,a,b]` and `g[x,y,z,a,b]`, where the variables are restricted to a set of values: x $\in$ [x0, x1], y $\in$ [y0, y1], z $\in$ [z0, z1], a $\in$ [a0, a1], b $\in$ [b0, b1]. I can find the minimum and maximum values within the restrictions using `Minimize` and `Maximize`.

These two functions are the `X` and `Y` coordinates of a point, I am using them to show some paths using `ParametricPlot` and to draw graphics using `Graphics`. The thing is, I need to know the boundaries which define the possible locations of the point.

How could I find the contour of the area for which the `(X,Y)` plot of these two functions is defined?

**EDIT1:**

I have tried to do it in two different ways.

1.
Using `ParametricRegion`:

> R = ParametricRegion[{Xt[X2, Th3, La1, La2, La3, La4, 
>         La5] /. {X2 -> X2in, 
>         La3 -> La3in} /. {Th3 -> Th3in, 
>        La4 -> La4in, La5 -> La5in},     Yt[X2, Th3, La1, La2, La3, La4, La5] /. {X2 -> X2in, 
>         La3 -> La3in} /. {Th3 -> Th3in, 
>        La4 -> La4in, La5 -> La5in}}, {{La1, dA1min, dA1max}, {La2, 
>       dA2min, dA2max}}];

And trying to represent it by:

> Region[R]

This is not able to give a result (it is still running after about 10h and 8GB of RAM).

2.
Using `ParametricPlot`

> ParametricPlot[{{Xt[X2, Th3, La1, La2, La3, La4, La5], 
>       Yt[X2, Th3, La1, La2, La3, La4, La5]}} /. {X2 -> 
>       X2min, Th3 -> Th3min, La3 -> dA3min,     La4 -> dA4min, La5 -> dA5min}, {La1, dA1min, dA1max}, {La2, dA2min,    dA2max}, AspectRatio
>   -> Automatic]

This is able to give a result relatively fast (40s and <2GB of RAM).

[image: Parametric Plot]

But unfortunately, `ParametricPlot` can't plot regions depending on more than 2 variables.

Just to give some insight into the problem, (`Xt`, `Yt`) give the position of a point from a body in a machine. I need to obtain the 'range of action' of this point. I need to find the contour of the area (or the area itself) in which the point can be located. The problem is that the point depends on 5 (6) variables.

Comment: I guess `ParametricRegion` is the way to go but hard to say without example. Maybe it will take more time than to generate point cloud for random point from the domain.

Comment: I have been trying to use `ParametricRegion`, but it takes an awful lot of time to give the results with 2/5 variables. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It is kind of strange that using `ParametricPlot` with 2 variables is much faster than `ParametricRegion` with the same 2 variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dark blue region is the place where different combinations of parameter values give the same (X,Y) combination. Maybe this superposition/overlap of points is the reason why `ParametricRegion` is not able to give an output.

I have *more or less found the solution* to this: plotting variables in pairs with the correct choice of maximum and minimum values and overlapping them.

The output is:

[image]

Once checked that this visual representation covers the whole region, it is now possible to identify the curves that define the edges and draw only them.